# Access control for one Publisher and multiple Subscribers

Tags: c, linux

I have a block of shared memory that multiple processes access.

To this block of memory, I have one process that writes/updates information (which I'm calling a Publisher), and I have more than one process that is reading this data (which I'm calling Subscribers).

This leads me to believe that, because I don't want the Subscribers to read in the middle of a write/update from the Publisher, I need to implement access control, to guarantee that the data currently in shared memory is fully updated before the Subscribers take it (no reading in the middle of a write).

This is the behavior I'm trying to design:

- Publisher may modify shared memory, but only when no other Subscriber is currently reading from the memory.
- Any Subscriber may read from shared memory, so long as the Publisher is not currently modifying it.
- Subscribers may not modify shared memory, only read; therefore, Consumers are allowed to read concurrently (assuming the Publisher is not modifying the shared memory).

The first solution I thought of is a simple mutex, or semaphore of size 1. This would mean that every time the Subscribers want to fetch new information, they would need to wait for the memory to be updated by the Publisher. However, this has the unintended consequences of Subscribers having to wait for other Subscribers, and the possibility that the Publisher gets delayed or locked out of the ability to publish new data if enough Subscribers exist on the system.

The second solution I thought of was looking into `shm` and found **`SHM_LOCK`** and **`SHM_UNLOCK`**, which seem useful to enforce the Publisher and Subscriber roles, but otherwise just seems to help reinforce **what** they can do, not necessarily *when* they can do it.

Alternatively, I have the reverse situation elsewhere, where the Subscribers from above become Publishers, each of which may or may not set a block of shared memory to a specific value. (They are not guaranteed to write to the block of memory, but the value is guaranteed to be the same across Publishers if they do write.) The Publisher from above becomes a Subscriber.

Addendum:

- Each Publisher and Subscriber is an individual process.
- 'Shared memory' in my question represents multiple different caches of memory, not a single unit. I do not want all shared memory locked out from Subscriber(s) when my Publisher(s) issue an update to just one of N data units.
- The Publisher (from the first part) is a daemon. My logic is that I want the daemon to be doing a timely action, putting data somewhere; I don't want the daemon disturbed to any great extent by Subscribers.

My questions:

1. Is there a control scheme that can properly encode the logic above? 
   (Publisher sets and removes access, Subscribers read when accessible.)
2. In this context, are there better methods of publishing information to multiple processes? Or is shared memory the way to go in this situation?

Comment: There is a _[good tutorial here](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2017/winter/51081-1/LabFAQ/lab7/Semaphores.html)_ that discusses synchronization and semaphores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is referred to as a [read-write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock).

These are natively supported with pthreads with `pthread_rwlock_*`. [pthread.h](https://linux.die.net/include/pthread.h). Normally pthreads would be used for threads.

In the case of multiple processes you could implement a read-write lock with semaphores. Do a little bit more reading and research and that would easy enough to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: That was indeed what I was looking for! I figured something like this should be pretty straightforward, since this is definitely not some weird unique problem. Now that you mention semaphores, I can see how you would implement something for processes: Have one semaphore be of size N (for Subscribers), and one of size M (for Publishers). Subscribers call into a method and request read access, Publishers call in and request write access. Logic and mapping between checking the read semaphore and write semaphore to determine access.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty standard. There are plenty of other patterns too

Answer (score 0):

normally, you need **two** `mutex`es for that (or more exactly, two `cond`s, that can share the same `mutex`)  The reason is that only locking the acces with a complex conditional is prone to a problem where readers are continously overlapping and blocking the access to writers.  When using two `cond`s, you can give priority to the queue of writers and disallow the blocking of the resources for reading when there's a writer waiting to acquire.  Well, I'm supposing that the number of writers is far less than the number or readers, as you can hit the other side, and block readers because writers are overlapping and blocking them....

The most flexible approach is probably to allow writers and readers to act in sequence (well, readers can do in parallel) using a flip-flop and preparing the swith as soon as there's a worker in the other side waiting for access.

Anyway, as you have been suggested in other responses, take a look at the [read-write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) suggested in other responses.